# Android : Is there any best way to download files in android ?"Connection time out exception while downloading large files?

Tags: android, download

In my application i need to download loads of files around 800mb (max size of file). I had a listview , where each item contain download button where user can select any of downloads and one will be running other will be in queue.
I am downloading files in following way ........

```
private boolean  Download1(String urlString, int sectionNo) {

        try {

            File file = new File(mFile,state.getAbbrevation()+"."+sectionNo+".zip");
            Log.v("Download", urlString);
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            urlConnection = url.openConnection();
            inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
//          HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
//          HttpGet request = new HttpGet(urlString);
//          HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
//          BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamRead);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(
                    inputStream, 1024);
            ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(
                    file);
            int count = 0;
            while ((count = bis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                baf.append(buffer, 0, count);
                currentByteCount += count;
                if((currentByteCount - prevByteCount ) > 1000000  ){
                downloadTask.loadProgress(currentByteCount);
                prevByteCount = currentByteCount;
                }
            }
            fileOutputStream.write(baf.toByteArray());
            fileOutputStream.close();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            handler.sendMessage(Message.obtain(handler, MSG_DOWNLOAD_FAILED, e.getMessage()));
            return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.v(TAG, e.getMessage());
            handler.sendMessage(Message.obtain(handler, MSG_DOWNLOAD_FAILED, e.getMessage()));
            return false;
        } finally {
            try {
                if(inputStream != null){
                inputStream.close();
                inputStream = null;
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

While downloading files some times am getting connection time out exception . Please can any one tell me how to avoid these exception ? Is there any better and fastest way to download files in android . If there is any such apis. Please let me know.

```
04-19 15:44:52.591: WARN/System.err(18199): java.net.SocketException: Connection timed out
04-19 15:44:52.591: WARN/Smack/Packet(209): notify conn break (IOEx), close connection
04-19 15:44:52.591: DEBUG/Smack(209): [XMPPConn] close connection, notifyClosed=false
04-19 15:44:52.591: WARN/System.err(18199):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.read(Native Method)
04-19 15:44:52.591: WARN/System.err(18199):     at dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedNetworkSystem.read(BlockGuard.java:273)
04-19 15:44:52.591: WARN/System.err(18199):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:458)
04-19 15:44:52.591: WARN/System.err(18199):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:85)
04-19 15:44:52.591: WARN/System.err(18199):     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:319)
04-19 15:44:52.591: WARN/System.err(18199):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.FixedLengthInputStream.read(FixedLengthInputStream.java:44)
04-19 15:44:52.591: WARN/System.err(18199):     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:319)
04-19 15:44:52.591: WARN/System.err(18199):     at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
04-19 15:44:52.591: WARN/System.err(18199):     at com.logictreeit.pilot.utils.Download.Download1(Download.java:245)
04-19 15:44:52.591: WARN/System.err(18199):     at com.logictreeit.pilot.utils.Download.access$4(Download.java:225)
04-19 15:44:52.591: WARN/System.err(18199):     at com.logictreeit.pilot.utils.Download$DownloadTask.doInBackground(Download.java:171)
04-19 15:44:52.591: WARN/System.err(18199):     at com.logictreeit.pilot.utils.Download$DownloadTask.doInBackground(Download.java:1)
04-19 15:44:52.591: WARN/System.err(18199):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
04-19 15:44:52.591: WARN/System.err(18199):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
04-19 15:44:52.591: WARN/System.err(18199):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
04-19 15:44:52.591: WARN/System.err(18199):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
04-19 15:44:52.591: WARN/System.err(18199):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
04-19 15:44:52.591: WARN/System.err(18199):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

Regards,
Srinivas

Answer (score 0):

hi Srinicas just try following function it will download successfully without any exception when download complete it will return true.

if any problems than comment on ans.

```
public static boolean DownloadFileFromNet(Activity activity,String path,String filename,Double totalSize)
{


    boolean status_download = false;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(path);
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.connect();

        String filepath = pathTobeDownload \\like your sdcard

        //this will be used to write the downloaded data into the file we created
        FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(filepath);

        //this will be used in reading the data from the internet
        InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

        //variable to store total downloaded bytes

        double downloadedSize = 0.0;

        //create a buffer...
        byte[] buffer = new byte[5000];
        int bufferLength = 0; //used to store a temporary size of the buffer

        //now, read through the input buffer and write the contents to the file
            while ( (bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0 ) 
            {
            //add the data in the buffer to the file in the file output stream (the file on the sd card

            fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
            //add up the size so we know how much is downloaded
            downloadedSize += bufferLength;
            percentage = (int) ((downloadedSize / totalSize) * 100);

        }
        //close the output stream when done
        fileOutput.close();
        downloadedSize = 0.0;
        percentage = 0;
        status_download = true; 
    //catch some possible errors...
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) 
    {
        status_download = false;
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) 
    {
        status_download = false;
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return status_download;
}
```

Comment: 04-19 11:46:30.149: DEBUG/SntpClient(60): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol

Comment: srinivas i think your file is too large.